# Wait for all child processes avoiding the suspended processes

Tags: c, subprocess, signals, waitpid

I'm trying to write a shell and I came across this problem: after I run the `fork()` and execute the commands, in the main process I wait for all child processes like this:

```
while (wait(NULL) > 0);
```

But when I try to suspend a child process, the main process won't go past this loop.

So how do I wait only for non suspended processes?
I could try to save the `pid_t` of all started sub processes then check if they are suspended but I thought maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Does this help?
https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait
I mean, it will "wake up" whenever a child changes it's state and returns a pid_t, should work, haven't tested it.

Comment: @punkkeks ty, but I've already read the man and I couldn't really find an answer

Comment: [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html) gives you more control over what to wait for.  It may be `WNOHANG` that you're looking for.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yea, I think I'll just go with saving the `pid_t` of subprocesses then `waitpid()` for non suspended processes for now, somehow...

Comment: Unsure about your wording. "*suspended*" would be "stopped" (can be "continued") or "ended" ("terminated", "dead")?

Comment: @alk yes, my bad. I meant when `ctrl-Z` is pressed.

Comment: Ok, so you want to end the `while`-loop if a child was suspended or ended, or both?

Comment: @alk I think both

Answer (score 1):

To wait for any child, either exited (aka ended, terminated) or stopped (aka suspended) use the `waitpid()` instead.

```
int wstatus;

{
  pid_t result;

  while (result = waitpid(-1, &wstatus, WUNTRACED)) /* Use WUNTRACED|WCONTINUED 
                                      to return on continued children as well. */
  {
    if ((pid_t) -1 = result)
    {
      if (EINTR = errno)
      {
        continue;
      }

      if (ECHILD == errno)
      {
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); /* no children */
      }

      perror("waitpid() failed");

      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }
}

if (WEXITED(wstatus))
{
  /* child exited normally with exit code rc = ... */
  int rc = WEXITSTATUS(wstatus);
  ...
}
else if (WIFSIGNALED(wstatus)
{
  /* child exited by signal sig = ... */
  int sig = WTERMSIG(wstatus);
  ...
}
else if (WSTOPPED(wstatus))
{
  /* child stopped by signal sig = ... */
  int sig = WSTOPSIG(wstatus);
  ...
}
else if (WCONTINUED(wstatus))
{
  /* child continued (occurs only if WCONTINUED was passed to waitpid()) */
}
```